# How to fill the gap in bootstrap horizontal card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a website that contains a horizontal bootstrap card and I want to fill the image to the full of the height of the left side of the horizontal card. Here are My codes!

```
  <div
          class="card mb-3 card_focus"
          style="max-width: 60rem; height: 100%"
        >
          <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div
                class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3 d-flex"
                style="max-width: 100%; height: 20rem"
              >
                <div class="card-body">
                  <i class="fas fa-file-code"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural
                  lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit
                  longer.
                </p>
                <p class="card-text">
                  <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and my  related CSS

```
#main_cont div div i {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: clamp(70px, 6vw, 200px);
}
```

here is how it is looking right now:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin-bottom: 0% !important;` to `class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3 d-flex"` like this:

```html
<html lang="en">
   
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <title>Bright!</title>
   </head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <body bgcolor='#303030'link=" #ffbd59" vlink=" #ffbd59" alink=" #ffbd59">
      <div
         class="card mb-3 card_focus"
         style="max-width: 60rem; height: 100%"
         >
         <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-4">
               <div
                  class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3 d-flex"
                  style="max-width: 100%; height: 20rem;margin-bottom: 0% !important "
                  >
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <i class="fas fa-file-code"></i>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">
                     This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural
                     lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit
                     longer.
                  </p>
                  <p class="card-text">
                     <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
                  </p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

A [Froala](https://froala.com/design-blocks/) design block will help you to understand the basic layouts. I hope it will be a good addition!

***Example***

[image]

***Code***

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="fdb-block">
  <div class="col-fill-left" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/3U2Fd7P.jpg);">
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-5 text-center">
        <h1>Froala Blocks</h1>
        <p class="lead">When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove</p>

        <p class="mt-4"><a href="https://www.froala.com">Learn More <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```